# Static vs dynamic allocated arrays

Tags: data-structures

I am trying to learn CS fundamentals and I am confused by static vs dynamic allocated arrays.  My only programming experience is JavaScript and all online resources I am using refer to C language.

A dynamic allocated array is made when the application starts and it cannot be resized.  So how is this different from static allocated array, if to expand the array you have to make a new and bigger array and copy over the contents?

Comment: I think that this question is better suited at [SO] because it is a programming issue.

Comment: By static do you mean the memory in the function that is preserved between calls or the memory that is automatically created and destroyed? To avoid further confusions VLA (variable length arrays in C) are also not resizeable. If you want resizeable memory maybe realloc would be helpful, but it also copy the array to new location if in the current is not enough place for resize (increasing the array).

Comment: This has already been explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385322/difference-between-static-memory-allocation-and-dynamic-memory-allocation

Answer (score 2):

No, a dynamically allocated array is created when the program creates it, in the size the program wants to create it, and it exists until the point of time when the program destroys it.